# writing function in R

Tags: r, function

I want to write a function to select `i` and `j` from the number of columns in `ret_Nifty`, while sum of `i` and `j` should be 5.

```
optimize.portfolio(R = ret_Nifty[, i:j], portfolio = ObjSpec, 
                   xxxxxx = "xxx",
                   search_size = 2000, trace = TRUE, 
                   traceDE = 5, itermax = 50)
```

But I’m not able to write a function for the same to select both variables.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Greetings! What is `ret_Nifty`? Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. calculate which column numbers add to 5 from every combination:

```r
get_ij <- function(df, adds_to){
  max_col <- ncol(df)
  x <- t(combn(1:max_col, 2))
  x[rowSums(x) == adds_to,] 
}

get_ij(mtcars, 5)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    4
#> [2,]    2    3
```